# how to show first value in Map<String, String> in select option and get second value when seleted?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have Map< Code, Name >, both of them is String, i pass this Map in to jsp with get method and show the Name in select option list. But i want get the Code when i select the Name and send back to Servlet, because i will need Code to query in sql, the Name can be duplicate in database but the code is unique.How can i do that, any advice for me?

I just use jquery, servlet, jsp, please don't use other things like Gson, Json, JSTL. This project is limited and can't use any other libs.

This is my example code to get Map< Code,Name > but in pro Map must get from database:
JSP:

```
<select id="selectgroup" name="selectgroup">
    <option>Group1</option>
    <option>Group2</option>
</select>
<select id="selectcity" name="selectcity">
</select>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selectgroup").change( function(event){
        var text='';
        var name = $("#selectgroup").val();
        $.get('Select', {
                comName : name
        }, function(responseText) {
            $("#selectcity").empty();
            var listEmp = responseText.replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
            var arrayEmp = listEmp.split(", ");
            arrayEmp.forEach(function(emp){
            var city = emp.split("=");
            if(city[1] != undefined){
            $("#selectcity").append(
                    '<option value="' + city[1] + '">' + city[1] + '</option>'     
                    );
            }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

And Servlet:

```
String comNameChanged = request.getParameter("comName")+"";
            if(comNameChanged.equals("Group1")){
                Map<String, String> ind = new HashMap<String, String>();
                //List<String> ind = new ArrayList<String>();
                ind.put("001","New delhi");
                ind.put("002","Tamil Nadu");
                ind.put("004","Kerala");
                ind.put("005","Andhra Pradesh");
                response.setContentType("text/plain");
                response.getWriter().print(ind);
            }
            if(comNameChanged.equals("Group2")) {
                Map<String, String> us = new HashMap<String, String>();
                //List<String> ind = new ArrayList<String>();
                us.put("001","NewYork");
                us.put("002","Hawai");
                us.put("004","Test");
                us.put("005","Cali");
                response.setContentType("text/plain");
                response.getWriter().print(us);         
            }
```

Thank for help.

Comment: Inspire us to answer your question by giving some code you have worked on so far.

Comment: I have add some code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

```
 <select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Place the name of the Code enum into the value attribute of the option element.

Comment: But the select list can be changed because i get it from database. Anyway thank for help.